# React native: force fetch to use WiFi

Tags: http, react-native, mobile, wifi

Both Android and iOS will route requests through mobile data if WiFi has no internet connection.

I'm trying to route requests to a WiFi device (192.168.1.1 IP), and I hoped that the OS would be smart enough to route internal IP requests through the WiFi (which shares the same submask), but I hoped wrong. Even in this case, mobile data will be used.

Sadly, neither fetch nor RNFetchBlob support anything to indicate where to route the requests through.

On the other hand, I have found some articles (https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/connecting-your-app-to-wi-fi-device.html) that explain how to do this in Android, but adding a native integration that allows some requests to go through WiFi, while others through Mobile (the app still needs internet for other tasks) seems like a very complicated implementation task, mostly because I would need to re-implement the fetch API with this behaviour. Basically, I would need to implement a full HTTP client and expose it to react.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this? I want to do the same

Comment: Not yet, I have some ideas, but it hasn't been a priority. On the JavaSide, RNFetchBlob could be updated to set a custom network connection rather than the default one. No idea for ios.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-wifi

This npm package helped me with this issue forcing to fetch data over wifi instead of mobile network. May be useful for you.

Comment: Ended up adding a PR to the react-native-fetch-blob library in order to support wifi-only settings, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: @CristianoCoelho Is your PR merged to master. Can you please point me to your PR ?

Comment: It was merged, see https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/pull/497